# clang-format and lttng TP_ENUM_VALUES/ctf_enum_value

Tags: clang-format, lttng

When using Clang-format to format a file with LTTNG trace definitions, the default settings makes the ctf_enum_value indentation quite ugly:

```
TRACEPOINT_ENUM(com_fafa,
                fafa_enum,
                TP_ENUM_VALUES(ctf_enum_value("AAA", AAA)
                                   ctf_enum_value("BBB", BBB)
                                       ctf_enum_value("CCC", CCC)))
```

Is there any option to get clang-format to align the ctf_enum_values like below instead?

```
TRACEPOINT_ENUM(com_fafa,
                fafa_enum,
                TP_ENUM_VALUES(ctf_enum_value("AAA", AAA)
                               ctf_enum_value("BBB", BBB)
                               ctf_enum_value("CCC", CCC)))
```

I suppose the problem is that there are no commas in these lists, which clang-format probably don't like...

Using "ContinuationIndentWidth: 0" as pointed out in answer below works well in some cases, but for others it willmake it worse, for example you might get this:

```
TRACEPOINT_EVENT(
com_fafa,
L_ERROR_fafa,
TP_ARGS(const enum fafa_type, e_code_, const int, msg_type_, const char*, file_line_),
TP_FIELDS(ctf_string(file_line, file_line_) ctf_integer(int, e_code, e_code_) ctf_integer(int, msg_type, msg_type_)
          ctf_integer_nowrite(int, u_trace_id, -1) ctf_string_nowrite(e_msg, "")))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of LTTng 2.10.1, `ctf_enum_value()` gets translated into [this](https://github.com/lttng/lttng-ust/blob/v2.10.1/include/lttng/ust-tracepoint-event.h#L132):

```
#define ctf_enum_value(_string, _value)                                 \
        {                                                               \
                .start = {                                              \
                        .value = lttng_is_signed_type(__typeof__(_value)) ? \
                                (long long) (_value) : (_value),        \
                        .signedness = lttng_is_signed_type(__typeof__(_value)), \
                },                                                      \
                .end = {                                                \
                        .value = lttng_is_signed_type(__typeof__(_value)) ? \
                                (long long) (_value) : (_value),        \
                        .signedness = lttng_is_signed_type(__typeof__(_value)), \
                },                                                      \
                .string = (_string),                                    \
        },
```

As you can see, the comma is included in the output. This is because otherwise, the comma would be interpreted as a `TP_ENUM_VALUES()` macro parameter separator, and this would limit the number of enumeration values you can put in `TP_ENUM_VALUES()`.

I guess macros are a problem for ClangFormat because they can't necessarily be parsed as C/C++. You might fall into more problems with other macros and have to do some manual formatting for some of them.

In the meantime, my solution would be to set the ClangFormat [`ContinuationIndentWidth`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) option to 0, for example:

```
clang-format -style '{BasedOnStyle: llvm, ContinuationIndentWidth: 0}' my-tp.h
```

Given your input, this command prints:

```
TRACEPOINT_ENUM(com_fafa, fafa_enum,
                TP_ENUM_VALUES(ctf_enum_value("AAA", AAA)
                               ctf_enum_value("BBB", BBB)
                               ctf_enum_value("CCC", CCC)))
```

Comment: It works for some entries.
But for others, it becomes even worse. I'll update the question with example.